# Join array objects into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
var Data = [{
"words": [
    "dolor",
    "sit",
    "amet",
    "consectetur"
],
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum."
}, {
"words": [
    "adipisicing",
    "elit",
    "sed",
    "do"
],
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum."
}];
```

How can I join all the words into one string, separated by single pipe symbol "|" ?
The desired output should look like this:
(dolor|sit|amet|consectetur|adipisicing|elit|sed|do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do This

```
Data.map(function(obj){ return obj.words.join("|") }).join("|");
```

Returns 
 "dolor|sit|amet|consectetur|adipisicing|elit|sed|do"

Comment: Regarding IE support, `map` is only supported in IE9 and up. There's a [polyfill here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you need to support older IEs.