# Find and highlight all occurrences of a word from an array and display matching description

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, jquery-ui

I have an array named **Data**, which holds all the words I want to find and highlight and display description for those words.
I used the answer from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562447/join-array-objects-into-a-string) to join the words and use them in **RegExp**.

```
var w = Data.map(function(obj){ return obj.words.join("|") }).join("|");   
var words = "(" + w + ")";
var wordsToReplace = new RegExp("\\b" + words + "\\b","g")
```

This works great, except only for non accented letters. Words should be wrapped in a **span** element, I'd like to use the jQuery UI tooltip for displaying description. As it was answered in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617600/show-tooltip-text-according-to-an-elements-class).
I tried to solve the problem with jQuery **:contains** selector, **RegExp** and various **highlight plugins**, but with no luck. The problem was always with accented letters or a script wouldn't find whole word and it highlighted only root of the word.

[Test JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ukw9c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to highlight them and show tooltips:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var src_str = $(".content").html();
    for(var i=0;i<Data.length;i++){
        for(var word=0;word<Data[i].words.length;word++){
        var term = Data[i].words[word];
        term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "i");
        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark data-tooltip-index='"+i+"' >$1</mark>");
        src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
        }
    }
    $(".content").html(src_str);

    $( document ).tooltip({
        items: "mark",
        content: function () {
            var index = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-index");
            return Data[index].desc;
        }
    });

}); // document ready end
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/Ukw9c/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It finds only first instance of each word and if the word is inside another word it highlight's it too (e.g. it highlights word "delší" inside "nejdelší" in second paragraph)